# How can I use from_db_value() in django model?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use `from_db_value()` in Django model with DateTimeField.

However, It seems not to work as I want.

Though I have looked for some example for this, I couldn't.

Could you offer a example using `from_db_value()`?

Below is what I did.

```
class DateTimeField2(models.DateTimeField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif timezone.is_aware(value):
            print "localtime"
            return timezone.localtime(value)
        else:
            return value
```

It is to change timezone with local not UTC django returns.

But Django still returns `datetime` with `UTC` tiemzone even though It prints "localtime" statement.

I am using `Django 1.8.3` and also set `settings.TIME_ZONE` well.